# disable an active itimer

Tags: c++

I'm using the `setitimer` function in order to set an `ITIMER_VIRTUAL` timer, using a pointer to some `struct itimerval`. this is a virtual timer (runs only when the process has control) and sends a `SIGVTALRM` signal the moment it  reaches zero.
My question is - after calling `setitimer`, is there any way to disable an active timer, so this signal would not go off when the timer finishes? or is the only way to ignore it now would be setting a SIGNAL MASK ordering the program to ignore this signal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page, just call `setitimer()` again, with the same timer handle and the `it_value` field of the itimerval struct set to zero.

You can disable it immeditately:

> Setting  it_value  to  0 shall  disable a timer, regardless of the value of it_interval.

Or after it next fires:

> Setting it_interval to 0 shall disable a timer after its next expiration (assuming it_value is non-zero).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Turned out my problem was caused by trying to disable the timer by calling `setitimer()` using a different `struct itimerval`, with its `it_value` set to zero. Instead I should have just changed the `it_value` of the original `struct itimerval` to zero and reset the `setitimer()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Call `settimer` and set `it_value` to `0` to stop the timer.